# Building NTP tools

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, openssl, ntp

I am trying to make a custom version of the NTPQ tool which requires the source from NTP and OpenSSL.

Getting the source and tools has been fairly straightforward but connecting NTP & OpenSSL has been a non-starter.

The NTP releases don't say which versions of OpenSSL are supported so I'm getting lots of errors and also complaints about missing .lib files (libeay32.lib in particular).

Has anyone managed to build this with VS2013, and if so - which versions?

**DEV SETUP**

*Visual Studio*

Visual Studio 2013

*NTP source code version*

ntp-4.2.8p8

*OpenSSL version*

openssl-1.1.0c.tar

*Perl version*

ActivePerl 5.24

**OPENSSL STEPS**

Ran these steps from the INSTALL document in a command prompt (as admin):

```
perl Configure VC-WIN32
...\Tools\vsvars32.bat
nmake
nmake test
nmake install
```

These all ran clean and created a branch with some headers and .lib files but the following are missing (and are required by NTP):

```
libeay32.lib
ntpd.lib
```

Comment: Please forgive me for asking... Do you want to work on the compiler errors; or do you only want the Yes/No question answer? You might also consider adding a link to NTPQ tools.

Comment: Ideally both - if I can find out someone has gotten it working on my setup and sources, that would be good to know but I'm also keen to address the issues if possible. I'll clear down the builds and start over as it is possible the workarounds I've put in place may have contributed to the issues. It would also be good to get people's views on how to get round the problems as it has been a fair old while since I did any C or Perl.